# fatal: Could not read from remote repository. When I push my local repo to remote server

Tags: git

In my remote server I have a directory `/var/www/html/Qiyun02-server`, and in it I use:

```
git init --bare Qiyun02-server
```

created a repo named `Qiyun02-server`.

and in my Qiyun02 project of my local Mac, I use

```
git remote add origin 103.15.22.21:/var/www/html/Qiyun02-server:Qiyun02-server
```

added the remote origin.

Then :

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'my first commit for remote origin'
```

Then I push to the remote server:

```
git push --set-upstream origin master
```

But I get bellow errors:

```
MacBook-Pro:Qiyun02 ldl$ sudo git push --set-upstream origin master 
Password:
root@103.15.22.21's password: 
fatal: '/var/www/html/Qiyun02-server:Qiyun02-server' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: You can't just init a repo and expose it over HTTP; the web server has to understand Git-specific actions. Also, `103.15.22.21:/var/www/html/Qiyun02-server:Qiyun02-server` doesn't even remotely look like a valid remote URL.

Comment: @CodeCaster how can I upload the code to remote server by git?

Comment: By running a module in your web server that understands Git.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not providing the correct URL path.

This is mistake :   git remote add origin 103.15.22.21:/var/www/html/Qiyun02-server:Qiyun02-server

Don't use url what you did above.

---

Follow the below way of adding url using HTTPS that's what your doing.

**HTTP/S:**

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

**`example <url> : https://github.com/xxx/xxx/`**

**SSH:**

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:username/new_repo
```

---

I suggest you follow this [beginner tutorial](http://blog.davidecoppola.com/2016/12/how-to-set-up-a-git-repository-locally-and-on-a-remote-server/), how to setup the git repo.

Comment: Do you mean I should use `git remote add origin 103.15.22.21:/var/www/html/Qiyun02-server/Qiyun02-server`?

Comment: Please read my answer clearly, I mentioned that is big blunder what your doing. You can't add something like that. For http protocol you have to provide the correct url path.